# Include only transition states in SQL query

Tags: sql, transition, presto

I have a table with customers and their purchase behaviour that looks as follows:

```
customer     shop       time
----------------------------
   1          5        13.30   
   1          5        14.33
   1          10       22.17
   2          3        12.15
   2          1        13.30
   2          1        15.55
   2          3        17.29
```

Since I want the shift in shop I need the following output

```
customer     shop       time
----------------------------
   1          5        13.30   
   1          10       22.17
   2          3        12.15
   2          1        13.30
   2          3        17.29
```

I have tried using

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer, shop  ORDER BY time ASC) AS a counter
```

and then only keeping all `counter=1`. However, this troubles me when the customer visits the same shop again later on, as with `customer=2` and `shop=3` in my example.

I came up with this:

```
WITH a AS 
(
    SELECT 
        customer, shop, time, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY time ASC) AS counter
    FROM 
        db
)
SELECT a1.*
FROM a a1
JOIN a AS a2 ON (a1.device = a2.device AND a2.counter1 + 1 = a1.counter1 AND a2.id <> a1.id)

UNION 

SELECT a.*
FROM a 
WHERE counter1 = 1
```

However, this is very inefficient and running it in AWS where my data is located results in a error telling me that

> Query exhausted resources at this scale factor

Is there any way to make this query more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  But the simplest solution uses `lag()`:

```
select customer, shop, time
from (select t.*, lag(shop) over (partition by customer order by time) as prev_shop
      from t
     ) t
where prev_shop is null or prev_shop <> shop;
```